# Showing that rotation about the origin and generally is an isometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, rotations, isometry, plane-geometry

Let $ρθ$ be the counterclockwise rotation about the origin $(0, 0)$ through the angle $θ$.

**1**) Give a proof in the 2-dimensional real plane that $ρθ$ is an isometry.

I am confused if I need to show that $d(p_\theta (x,y), (0,0)) = d((x,y), (0,0)) $ or if I need to pick two different arbitrary points and show that $d(p_\theta (x,y),p_\theta (r,s)) = d((x,y), (r,s)) $.

**2**) Prove that every general rotation $ρ$ of $R^2$ is an isometry of $R^2$

My thinking for this one is that I would be to show that given a fixed point $(r,s)$ and an arbitrary $(x,y)$, $d(p_\theta (x,y), (r,s)) = d((x,y), (r,s)) $. I'm not sure how to go about proving this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By “general rotation” do you mean rotation about an arbitrary point instead of the origin?

Comment: Yes. As in you can take any point in $R^2$ and that would be the center of the rotation map.

Comment: For part 1, an isometry preserves the distance between every pair of points, so it’s the latter. You could, of course, translate after rotating so that one of the points became the origin, but that won’t change the algebra that needs to be done. Hint for part 2: what do you get when you compose two isometries?

Comment: The composition of two isometries is an isomtery so If I take what I do in part 1 and apply it to something with a center away from the origin it should prove the conjecture. Right?

Comment: Right. Remember to translate back to the original origin after the rotation.

Comment: Adding an answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

1) An isometry preserves the distance between every pair of points, so you need to show $d(\rho_\theta(P_1),\rho_\theta(P_2))=d(P_1,P_2)$ for an arbitrary pair of points.

2) Decompose the general rotation into a sequence of transformations that you already know to be isometries (you'll use the result from part 1).